# error in php, ($baseObject) must be of type DateTimeInterface, bool given c\

Tags: php

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: date_diff(): Argument #1 ($baseObject) must be of type DateTimeInterface, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\eris\process.php:161 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\eris\process.php(161): date_diff(false, Object(DateTime)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\eris\process.php(10): doRegister() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\eris\process.php on line 161
```

Here is the code from line 161

```
function doRegister(){
    global $mydb;
    if (isset($_POST['btnRegister'])) { 
        $birthdate =  $_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'];
        $age = date_diff(date_create($birthdate),date_create('today'))->y;
    
        if ($age < 20){
            message("Invalid age. 20 years old and above is allowed.", "error");
            redirect("index.php?q=register");
        }else{
            $autonum = New Autonumber();
            $auto = $autonum->set_autonumber('APPLICANT');
                 
            $applicant =New Applicants();
            $applicant->APPLICANTID = date('Y').$auto->AUTO;
            $applicant->FNAME = $_POST['FNAME'];
            $applicant->LNAME = $_POST['LNAME'];
            $applicant->MNAME = $_POST['MNAME'];
            $applicant->ADDRESS = $_POST['ADDRESS'];
            $applicant->SEX = $_POST['optionsRadios'];
            $applicant->CIVILSTATUS = $_POST['CIVILSTATUS'];
            $applicant->BIRTHDATE = $birthdate;
            $applicant->BIRTHPLACE = $_POST['BIRTHPLACE'];
            $applicant->AGE = $age;
            $applicant->USERNAME = $_POST['USERNAME'];
            $applicant->PASS = sha1($_POST['PASS']);
            $applicant->EMAILADDRESS = $_POST['EMAILADDRESS'];
            $applicant->CONTACTNO = $_POST['TELNO'];
            $applicant->DEGREE = $_POST['DEGREE'];
            $applicant->create();
    
            $autonum = New Autonumber();
            $autonum->auto_update('APPLICANT');
    
            message("You are successfully registered to the site. You can login now!","success");
            redirect("index.php?q=success");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `date_create()` returns `FALSE` if the argument isn't a valid date.

Comment: Check the value of `date_create($birthdate)`

Comment: What is the value of `$birthdate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, we like to sanitize user input. You aren't doing that, and more importantly - ***you're assuming*** that the user is intelligent.

```php
function doRegister()
{
    global $mydb;
    if (isset($_POST['btnRegister'])) {

        $year  = isset($_POST['year'])  ? intval($_POST['year'])  : 1990;
        $month = isset($_POST['month']) ? intval($_POST['month']) : 8;
        $day   = isset($_POST['day'])   ? intval($_POST['day'])   : 1;

        $birthdate = "$year-$month-$day";
```

Adding some very basic sanitization to your inputs, with some sane defaults (tweak to your liking). Or you could just make sure that they're all set before continuing:

```php
function doRegister()
{
    global $mydb;
    if (isset($_POST['btnRegister'])) {

        $year  = intval($_POST['year']);
        $month = intval($_POST['month']);
        $day   = intval($_POST['day']);

        if ($year == 0 || $month == 0 || $day == 0) {
            echo "You must enter year/month/day";
            exit();
        }

        $birthdate = "$year-$month-$day";
```

Some additional bounds checking (e.g.: `if ($year < 1950 || $year > 2021) do_something();`) is also encouraged. Happy coding!